# I cannot save or print PDF/PS output when I create a document in Lyx

Tags: package-management, pdf, lyx

I installed Lyx (Processor) from the Ubuntu Software centre (Precise).  It allows me to create and save  Lyx documents but only allows me to view the PDF/PS  rendition.  Is there an additional package I need to install to have this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the answer to this question and for the sake of good housekeeping have answered my own question

I resolved this by installing **Document (PostScript, PDF) viewer (GTK+ version) (evence-gtk)**